# How to delete inet6 Link address automatically?

Tags: networking, ipv6

There is an inet6 addr on the eth0 interface:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:d9:46:f5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fed9:46f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4133 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:32902 (32.9 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024
```

I don't need this address and I use the following command to delete it:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 inet6 del fe80::20c:29ff:fed9:46f5/64
```

However, each time I restart the system, this address comes back.

How to disable the autoconfigured inet6 address?

Comment: Which Distro are you using ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This isn't the actual problem you're having. You should solve the _real_ problem instead.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use 
`sudo ifconfig eth0 del fe80::20c:29ff:fed9:46f5/64`

For permanent disable 
Add following entry in "`/etc/sysctl.conf`"

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and run

```
sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably configure that to not get assigned in the first place, but
I would just put the `ifconfig` command in `/etc/rc.local` so it gets run at startup.